# Gallery delete album with ajax fails on second

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've created a gallery where the user delete an album via ajax, my problem is that when i click the "delete" button it works the first time, everything runs fine and the folder and pictures gets deleted, but when i move on to the second album and try to delete it, ajax gives me success BUT nothing gets deleted! the error: function doesnt give me an error either (in console) the ajax runs like normal...

**Here is the button(form) that triggers ajax**

```
<form action='' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' id='album' name='album' value='$albid'>
<center><input type="submit" class="javagalleryAlbumDeleteBtn" name="createAlbum" value="Delete Album"></center>
</form>
```

**Here is the js file containing ajax**

```
// CHECK THAT DOCUMENT IS READY
$(document).ready(function() {

// This is the button we are looking for.
$('.javagalleryAlbumDeleteBtn').click(function() {

// Get values from form
var album = $("#album").val();

// Put the vars in a string
var dataString = 'album='+album;

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gallery/deleteAlbum.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){console.log(data);},
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {console.log(textStatus, errorThrown););

    }// End success

    }); // End ajax

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

    }); // End #login click

    }); // End document ready
```

**Here is the deleteAlbum.php file**

```
$getalbumid = $_POST['album'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT gallery_address FROM users_galleries WHERE gallery_id = '$getalbumid'") or die(mysql_error());
list($galaddress) = mysql_fetch_row($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){

// delete the pictures in the DB
mysql_query("DELETE FROM pictures WHERE picalbum = '$getalbumid' AND picowner = " . $_SESSION['id'] . "")or die(mysql_error());

// delete the album from the DB
mysql_query("DELETE FROM users_galleries WHERE gallery_id = '$getalbumid' AND gallery_userid = " . $_SESSION['id'] . "  LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());

// Function that deletes all content in folder and the folder
folderDelete($galaddress);

} // end delete
```

Comment: make your dataString like this dataString = 'album:album';

Comment: thanks for the headsup (i've changed it now) but doesnt realy solve my problem :/

Answer (score 1):

At first - your HTML page can't contain elements with same id, so in form :

```
<form action='' method='post'>
   <input type='hidden' id='album' name='album' value='$albid'>
   <center><input type="submit" class="javagalleryAlbumDeleteBtn" name="createAlbum" value="Delete Album"></center>
</form>
```

try to change on class. And in JS:

```
// Get values from form
var album = $(this).closest('form').find('.album').val();
```

this will help you with sending correct value of album ID to server side.

Second thing - look at MySQL injection article - http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php